# How to listen messageSent event in laravel 5.5

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.5

Hi I am a beginner for events and listeners in laravel. So please explain me how to achieve this :

**Aim :**

Send an email to user. And know whether email is sent or not.

**My Understanding :**

Laravel has in-built event `Illuminate\Mail\Events\MessageSent` to fire after email is sent and I have to write a listener to listen the event.

**What I did :**

To send email :

```
Mail::to($receiverAddress)->send(new SendNewUserPassword($content));
```

This is working fine. Able to send email to user successfully.

To listen messageSent event, I created this listener :

```
<?php

namespace App\Listeners;

use Illuminate\Mail\Events\MessageSent;
use Illuminate\Queue\InteractsWithQueue;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\ShouldQueue;

class LogSentMessage
{
    /**
     * Create the event listener.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Handle the event.
     *
     * @param  MessageSent  $event
     * @return void
     */
    public function handle(MessageSent $event)
    {
        return $event->message;
    }
}
```

To Register Event :

```
protected $listen = [
    'App\Events\Event' => [
        'App\Listeners\EventListener',
    ],

    'Illuminate\Mail\Events\MessageSent' => [
        'App\Listeners\LogSentMessage',
    ],
];
```

In Controller :

```
event(new MessageSent())
```

Please guide me **how to return the message handled in Listener from controller**. If my above approach is wrong explain me how to achieve it. This I am using for an api, so if sending mail is success/fail I want to know.

Answer (score 7):

You can pass data from the controller to the mailable, and then from the mailable to the listener

For example I have a model called `SendOrder` that I use to keep track the status of the email, so I pass this model from the controller to the listener

This is what you have to do from scratch

### In your controller

Pass the model to your Mailable constructor

```
$send_order = SendOrder::create(['status' => 'received', 'email' => 'foo@example.com']);

Mail::to($receiverAddress)->send(new SendNewMail($send_order));
```

### In the Mailable `SendNewMail`

Class Mailable has a method `withSwiftMessage()` which you can use to store variables/objects that you can access later from the listener.

We will make a constructor that pass the model to the `build()` method where we can execute the `withSwiftMessage()` to store it for later.

```
use App\SendOrder;

class SendNewMail extends Mailable
{
     protected $send_order;

     public function __construct( SendOrder $send_order )
     {
         $this->send_order = $send_order;
     }
     public function build()
     {
         $send_order = $this->send_order;
         $this->withSwiftMessage(function ($message) use($send_order) {
               $message->send_order = $send_order;
         });

         // Do more stuffs

     }
}
```

### Create the listener

#### Register the event and listener in the file app/Providers/EventServiceProvider.php

```
protected $listen = 
    'Illuminate\Mail\Events\MessageSent' => [
        'App\Listeners\LogSentMessage',
    ],
];
```

#### Now execute the command:

`php artisan event:generate`

This will automatically generate the new listener **app\Listeners\LogSentMessage** with a template code that's connected to the built-in event **Illuminate\Mail\Events\MessageSent**

### In your Listener `LogSentMessage`

You can access the model this way:

```
public function handle(MessageSent $event)
{
    $send_order = $event->message->send_order;
    $send_order->update(['status' => 'sent']);
}
```

Comment: I was not aware that you can pass data from a mailable to a listener. Made my day. Thank you.

Comment: N.B. Laravel 9 replaces SwiftMailer with Symfony Mailer.   `withSwiftMessage` becomes `withSymfonyMessage` - see [here](https://github.com/laravel/framework/pull/38481) for more details.

Answer (score 2):

In your `EventServiceProvider` add your event and listener

```
protected $listen = [
       'Illuminate\Notifications\Events\NotificationSent' => [
       'App\Listeners\YourListenerClass',
    ],
];
```

and in YourListnerClass

```
public function handle(NotificationSent $event)
{

 //access your $event data here 
 //which includes notification details too

}
```

Comment: This is what I did. I explained this in my question. Now I want to get that message return back to controller when event is fired..

Comment: Event are async. It triggers when something happens.

Comment: Yes it triggers and we have listener to listen it, but how to catch that triggered message and return it to controller method

Comment: what are you trying to do?

Comment: I have an api to send email, when email is sent from laravel I want to return the message triggered from messageSent event in that api. Above I explained everything what i wrote in the code.

Answer (score 1):

Doing php `php artisan event:generate` will generate `App\Listeners\LogSentMessage` for you.

Edit the file for example:

```
public function handle(MessageSent $event)
{
    dd($event->message->getBody(), $event->message->toString());
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I was stuck forever and ever trying to get my EventServiceProvider to register the Illuminate\Mail\MessageSent event to a local listener. Every time that I tried to do
php artisan event:generate
I would get

```
Your application doesn't have any events matching the given criteria.
```

I finally found that my EventService provider was using

```
use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;
```

when I switched this to use

`use Illuminate\Foundation\Support\Providers\EventServiceProvider as ServiceProvider;`

The event was registered properly! Maybe this will help someone.